# Collation não reconhece acentuação

Tags: sql-server, acentuação, collation

Ttenho 2 bancos no SqlServer, banco `A` com o collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AS` e outro banco chamado `B` com o collation `Latin1_General_CI_AS`.

No banco A importa informações para o banco B.

Foi feita uma migração do sistemas desses bancos para outro local, agora o Banco A não reconhece acentuação (ex: ao invés de aparecer:

> IMPORTAÇÃO E MANUTENÇÃO

Aparece

> IMPORTAÃ+O E MANUTENÃ+O

Assim, acaba replicando para o Banco B.

Alguém já passou por um problema parecido e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Como é feita a tal importação? Me parece um problema com o software de importação, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Bom dia, na verdade